# For a final class why does when complain?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-when

So in the following code I get compilation error that "when must be exhaustive add necessary else":

```
class Test {

}

fun eval(e: Test): Int =
        when(e) {
            is Test -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
```

To clarify this is only code aimed to understand Kotlin (newbie here).
So `Test` can not be extended by any subclass by default behaviour of Kotlin.
So what are other cases that the `when` expects?
Using `sealed` also does not work in this case

Comment: Wild guesses: 1) The code that checks for exhaustivity isn't checking for conditions like this because there are better alternatives (`if`) and it wasn't worth the effort.   Or 2) Just because `Test` isn't open now, doesn't mean it won't be in the future. Meaning, if `eval()` is compiled and delivered, and then somebody opens `Test` and subclasses it, `eval()` will fail.

Comment: @Todd: Concerning (2) why is `eval` failing bad? I would say this is a good as the change in behavior (making it open) would be caught at compile time.

Comment: @Jim I didn't get that issue with sealed classes, i.e. listing all possible values is considered to be exhaustive. That's with Kotlin 1.3.41, FYI

Comment: @user2340612: Did you copy paste the code as I have it and used the keyword `sealed`?

Comment: @user2340612: Also how do I check which version of Kotlin my IDE uses?

Comment: @Jim not really.. I created a `sealed class Response` with 1 child `class Success : Response()`. Then `when(response) { is Success -> TODO() } ` is considered to be exhaustive. To check Kotlin version (assuming you're using IntelliJ IDE) just build your project, and in `Messages` tab (at the bottom) you'll see the version of `kotlinc`: something like `kotlinc-jvm 1.3.41`

Comment: @user2340612: Yes but what you did is not what I have in my post. That would work because of `Success`. Try removing `Success`

Comment: @Jim yeah I understand what you mean, in that case it won't work indeed. I don't know what's the reason behind that design decision, you should ask Jetbrains :-)

Answer (score 2):

Adding `sealed` without other changes is pointless: it makes the class abstract and impossible to subclass, so you'll never have an instance. I believe this is a compiler bug, it's very similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28249 though with `class` instead of `object`.

It's also a low-impact one, because if `is Test` is the only branch, you can just replace the entire `when` with the branch, and if it isn't, you can replace `is Test` with `else`.

Answer (score 0):

class Test

Because when needs default value for return, if the elements (e) is not matched anything it should be return default value

```
class Test

fun eval(e: Test): Int =
when (e) {
    is Test -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    else -> 7 //default value
}
```

other option is change return type as nullable in your function

```
fun eval(e: Test): Int? =
when (e) {
    is Test -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    else -> null
        }
```

**when**

> If when is used as an expression, else branch is mandatory, unless the compiler can prove that all
>   possible cases are covered with branch conditions

.

for more details refer [when-expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression)

if elements is single no point of use when. your  function may be simplified as below

```
fun eval(e: Test): Int = throw IllegalArgumentException()
```

Comment: But that is my question. Since `Test` is not possible to be sub classed what could fall in the `else` branch?

Comment: yes your are correct..  Thats case no needs to use 'when' use 'if' instead of that.

Comment: But my question is why `when` can not handle this? Is there some type that can be replaced that I am not thinking?

Comment: you want throw exception ?

Comment: No. My question is not how to fix the code. My question is why does `when` get confused here as there are no other sub types. Or are there? I am trying to understand `when` and classes in `Kotlin`

Comment: Please check @Todd's comments. It seems my question is not clear for everyone

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `when` have to be exhaustive when you want to use it in return/assign statement.

For example:

```
// let k be of Any? type:
when (k) {
    is Number -> { println("Ok, k is a Number") }
}
```

This is OK. You don't expect any result. If `k` is a number then something will be printed. Otherwise, nothing will happen.

So, the second example:

```
// k is the same
boolean isNumber = when (k) {
    is Number -> true;
}
```

But, what if boolean is not a number? Code will not compile, because your program would be in indefinite state.

So, what you can do? Your `when` have to be exhaustive. So, just add `else`. One of the pattern is, for example, to throw `IllegalStateException()` if case like your.

```
fun eval(e: Test): Int = when(e) {
    is Test -> 1
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("This should never happen!")
}
```

*Edit:*

Regarding to your comment. `e` actually can be something different than `Test`. It can be... Nothing.

I am completely aware about possibilities when it can happen and correctness of usage things like this. But, example below is completely OK and compiles without any problem. Maybe with reflection it would have some useful usage.

```
class Test

fun eval(e: Test): Int =
    when(e) {
        is Test -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }

fun getNothing(): Nothing {
    throw IllegalStateException()
}

fun main() {
    eval(getNothing())
}
```

Comment: Exhaustivity is understood. What isn't understood is why his `eval()` isn't exhaustive if `Test` isn't open for extension. In his example, `e` can't be anything other than `Test`.

Comment: @Todd: Exactly!

Comment: I've added a little example how (in theory) pass something different than `Test` there (I know that this code always will execute with runtime fail).

Answer (score 0):

**So what are other cases that the when expects?** - "else" because Test is not sealed class.

The error shows clearly that you need to add else condition, i tried to return 0 in else condition since the function return Integer and error gone.

```
class Test {

}

fun eval(e: Test): Int =
    when(e) {
        is Test -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        else -> 0 
    }
```

or you need to assign to var or val and return Int value as below,

```
fun eval(e: Test): Int {
    val i: Int = when (e) {
        is Test -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        else -> 0
    }
    return i
}
```